# Adapting to current screen orientation using segues

Tags: ios, segue, uiinterfaceorientation

A storyboard has tow ViewControllers-s, one for Portrait orientation (`VCPort` for short), another for landscape (`VCLand`). I want the application to switch automatically to correct layout when the device is rotated.
For that purpose I have two segues `portToLand` from VSPort to VCLand and `LandToPort` in opposite direction. Then I override `willRotateToScreenOrientation` as the following.

For VCPort class:

```
override func willRotateToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: NSTimeInterval)
{
    if toInterfaceOrientation.isLandscape {
        switchViewController()
    }
}

func switchViewController() {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("portToLand", sender: self)
}
```

For VCLand class I have `isPortrait` instead of `isLandscape` and `"landToPort"` instead of `"portToLand"`.

Everything works OK if the storyboard starts in Portrait orientation. When the storyboard starts while the device is in Landscape (e.g. with IPad Retina)  VCPort still gets the control as the first ViewController in chain and willRotateToScreen doesn't come. To make the application switch to Landscape layout in this case I place the following code in `viewDidLoad` for VCPort class:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   if UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation.isLandscape {
         switchViewController()
    }
 }
```

Tracing with debugger show thats performSegueWithIdentifier is called, but VCLand doesn't get the control, the application still shows VCPort layout! In assumption that I do it too early, I tried `viewWillAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad` - no difference.

Thanks for any comments.

Comment: This is not a good idea. Every time you rotate, you're creating a new view controller, so you'll be adding more and more controllers until you run out of memory.

Comment: The design of portrait and landscape are completely different? If not, you can use Autolayout constraints.

Comment: rdelmar. I will be happy to reuse same controller when the orientation returns. Is it possible?  BTW, as far as I remember, one Apple article mentions segues a a correct way of handling multiple orientations.

Comment: the_UB. The controls are same, but location against each other is completely different, so Autolayout won't help

Answer (score 0):

Just put a short delay before switching views. And moved the code to viewWillAppear, since the orientation may change while app is in pause:

```
   var timer : NSTimer?

   override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        let deviceOrientation = UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation
        var isLandscape : Bool;
        if deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientation.Unknown {
            isLandscape = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation.isLandscape
        } else  {
            isLandscape = deviceOrientation.isLandscape
        }

        if isLandscape {
            self.view.hidden = true
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.05, target: self, selector: Selector("switchViewController"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        } else {
            self.view.hidden = false
        }


    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        if (timer != nil) {
            timer!.invalidate()
            timer = nil
        }
    }
```